# Simple ObservableDictionary implementation

Tags: c#

My version of implementation ObservableDictionary. Its should work as ObservableCollection, I hope. Based on referencesource Dictionary implementation.

.NET 4.5 framework

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace Roing.CommonUI.Collections
{
    public class ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected IDictionary<TKey, TValue> Dictionary { get; }

        #region Constants (standart constants for collection/dictionary)

        private const string CountString = "Count";
        private const string IndexerName = "Item[]";
        private const string KeysName = "Keys";
        private const string ValuesName = "Values";

        #endregion

        #region .ctor

        public ObservableDictionary()
        {
            Dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
        }

        public ObservableDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
        {
            Dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(dictionary);
        }

        public ObservableDictionary(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
        {
            Dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(comparer);
        }

        public ObservableDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
        {
            Dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(dictionary,comparer);
        }

        public ObservableDictionary(int capacity, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
        {
            Dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(capacity, comparer);
        }

        public ObservableDictionary(int capacity)
        {
            Dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(capacity);
        }

        #endregion

        #region INotifyCollectionChanged and INotifyPropertyChanged

        public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion

        #region IDictionary<TKey, TValue> Implementation

        public TValue this[TKey key]
        {
            get
            {
                return Dictionary[key];
            }
            set
            {
                InsertObject(
                    key : key, 
                    value : value,
                    appendMode :  AppendMode.Replace, 
                    oldValue : out var oldItem);

                if (oldItem != null)
                {
                    OnCollectionChanged(
                        action: NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace,
                        newItem: new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value),
                        oldItem: new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, oldItem));
                }
                else
                {
                    OnCollectionChanged(
                        action: NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add,
                        changedItem: new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
                }
            }
        }

        public ICollection<TKey> Keys => Dictionary.Keys;

        public ICollection<TValue> Values => Dictionary.Values;

        public int Count => Dictionary.Count;

        public bool IsReadOnly => Dictionary.IsReadOnly;

        public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
        {
            InsertObject(
                key: key,
                value: value,
                appendMode: AppendMode.Add);

            OnCollectionChanged(
                action: NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add,
                changedItem: new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
        }

        public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
        {
            InsertObject(
                key: item.Key,
                value: item.Value,
                appendMode: AppendMode.Add);

            OnCollectionChanged(
                action: NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add,
                changedItem: new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(item.Key, item.Value));
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            if (!Dictionary.Any())
            {
                return;
            }

            var removedItems = new List<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>(Dictionary.ToList());
            Dictionary.Clear();
            OnCollectionChanged(
                action: NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset,
                newItems: null,
                oldItems: removedItems);
        }

        public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
        {
            return Dictionary.Contains(item);
        }

        public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
        {
            return Dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
        }

        public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            Dictionary.CopyTo(
                array: array,
                arrayIndex: arrayIndex);
        }

        public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return Dictionary.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public bool Remove(TKey key)
        {
            if(Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
            {
                Dictionary.Remove(key);
                OnCollectionChanged(
                    action: NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove,
                    changedItem: new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key,value));
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
        {
            if (Dictionary.Remove(item))
            {
                OnCollectionChanged(
                    action: NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove,
                    changedItem: item);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
        {
            return Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return Dictionary.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion

        #region IReadOnlyDictionary

        IEnumerable<TKey> IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Keys => Dictionary.Keys;
        IEnumerable<TValue> IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Values => Dictionary.Values;

        #endregion

        #region ObservableDictionary inner methods

        private void InsertObject(TKey key, TValue value, AppendMode appendMode)
        {
            InsertObject(key, value, appendMode, out var trash);
        }

        private void InsertObject(TKey key, TValue value, AppendMode appendMode, out TValue oldValue)
        {
            oldValue = default(TValue);

            if (key == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
            }

            if(Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var item))
            {
                if(appendMode == AppendMode.Add)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Item with the same key has already been added");
                }

                if (Equals(item, value))
                {
                    return;
                }

                Dictionary[key] = value;
                oldValue = item;
            }
            else
            {
                Dictionary[key] = value;
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged()
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(CountString);
            OnPropertyChanged(IndexerName);
            OnPropertyChanged(KeysName);
            OnPropertyChanged(ValuesName);
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
            {
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }

            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private void OnCollectionChanged()
        {
            OnPropertyChanged();
            var handler = CollectionChanged;
            handler?.Invoke(
                this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
                    action:NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }

        private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> changedItem)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged();
            var handler = CollectionChanged;
            handler?.Invoke(
                this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
                    action:action,
                    changedItem: changedItem));
        }

        private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> newItem, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> oldItem)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged();
            var handler = CollectionChanged;
            handler?.Invoke(
                this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
                    action: action,
                    newItem: newItem,
                    oldItem: oldItem));
        }

        private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, IList newItems)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged();
            var handler = CollectionChanged;
            handler?.Invoke(
                this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
                    action: action,
                    changedItems: newItems));
        }

        private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, IList newItems, IList oldItems)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged();
            var handler = CollectionChanged;
            handler?.Invoke(
                this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
                    action: action,
                    newItems: newItems,
                    oldItems: oldItems));
        }

        #endregion

        internal enum AppendMode
        {
            Add,
            Replace
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean for `c[1] = 0; c[1] = 0;` to cause two CollectionChanged events?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ```
>         protected IDictionary<TKey, TValue> Dictionary { get; }
> ```

I don't find this to be a very helpful name. FWIW my default choice for something like this would be `Wrapped`.

---

> ```
>         private const string CountString = "Count";
>         private const string IndexerName = "Item[]";
>         private const string KeysName = "Keys";
>         private const string ValuesName = "Values";
> ```

Why not `nameof` (except for `IndexerName`, obviously)?

---

IMO there are two useful constructors missing: `ObservableDictionary(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>)` and similarly with a comparer. If you've left them out because YAGNI then fair enough, but in that case I'm surprised at how many constructors were necessary.

---

> ```
>                 InsertObject(
>                     key : key, 
>                     value : value,
>                     appendMode :  AppendMode.Replace, 
>                     oldValue : out var oldItem);
>
>                 if (oldItem != null)
> ```

Hmm. Technically this isn't quite correct: after `dict[foo] = null;` a call to `dict[foo] = bar;` should be considered a replacement rather than an addition. That's why `TryGetValue` returns a `bool` and has an out-parameter for the value, rather than just returning the value and letting you test whether it's null. I suggest reworking so that `InsertObject` returns a `bool`.

---

> ```
>         public ICollection<TKey> Keys => Dictionary.Keys;
>
>         public ICollection<TValue> Values => Dictionary.Values;
> ```

My biggest concern with this implementation: shouldn't these two properties *also* be observable? I would rather bind an `Items` property to `Keys` than bind it to the dictionary with an `IValueConverter` to select the key.

---

> ```
>         public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
>         {
>             InsertObject(
>                 key: key,
>                 value: value,
>                 appendMode: AppendMode.Add);
>
>             OnCollectionChanged(
>                 action: NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add,
>                 changedItem: new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
>         }
>
>         public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
>         {
>             InsertObject(
>                 key: item.Key,
>                 value: item.Value,
>                 appendMode: AppendMode.Add);
>
>             OnCollectionChanged(
>                 action: NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add,
>                 changedItem: new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(item.Key, item.Value));
>         }
> ```

DRY: one of these methods should call the other one.

---

> ```
>             var removedItems = new List<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>(Dictionary.ToList());
> ```

Either use `new List<...>(Dictionary)` or use `Dictionary.ToList()`: you don't need both. (I prefer `ToList()` because it saves writing out the full type).

---

> ```
>         public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
>         {
>             return Dictionary.Contains(item);
>         }
>
>         public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
>         {
>             return Dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
>         }
> ```

Does your style guide allow `=>` notation for properties but not methods?

---

> ```
>         private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> changedItem)
>         {
>             OnPropertyChanged();
>             var handler = CollectionChanged;
>             handler?.Invoke(
>                 this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
>                     action:action,
>                     changedItem: changedItem));
>         }
> ```

What about the index of the changed item? I know it's a pain in the neck to implement, but it ensures maximum compatibility. If YAGNI, document that.

---

Finally, overall the code looks quite good. It uses modern syntactic sugar, and for the most part is well decomposed.

Answer (score 4):

Not bad overall, but there are a few problems:

- `Clear` throws an `ArgumentException`, because `Reset` events cannot reference old items.
- `this[TKey key].set` checks if `oldItem` isn't `null`. That only works for reference types. For value types this will only raise `Replace` events instead of `Add` events.
- I wouldn't expect replacing a value to trigger property change events for `Count` and `Keys`.

A few more notes:

- I would use `nameof` instead of constants where possible. Also, I find that creating constants for things that are only used in one place makes code a little harder to understand without providing any maintenance benefits.
- Why does `OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)` call `OnPropertyChanged()` if the given property name is empty or null? It's not used in practice (so it should just be removed) but it does introduce a risk for infinite recursion (during later code modifications).
- C# 7.0 added support for 'discards', using the special variable name `_`, so you can use that instead of `trash`.
- There are a few unused overloads of `OnCollectionChanged` that can be removed.
- The various `OnCollectionChanged` methods could be given more descriptive names, such as `OnCollectionReset`, `OnValueReplaced`, and so on.